# Angular - Observable and SwitchMap - How to show loader while async call ongoing

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I was checking the tour of heroes from the Angular documentation to mimic the behavior "search while you type".

You can find the [example here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#edit-the-herosearchcomponent-class)

I was wondering how I could show a loader while waiting for the search result.

I tried this:

```
this.results$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(() => this.searching = true),
    switchMap((term: string) => {
        this.searching = false;
        return (term && term.length > 0) ? this.myService.someCallToApi(term) : new Observable<Contact[]>();
    })
);
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `this.search = false` after http request

```
this.results$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(() => this.searching = true),
    switchMap((term: string) => {
        return (term && term.length > 0) ? this.myService.someCallToApi(term) : new Observable<Contact[]>();
    }),
    tap(() => this.searching =false),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're "taping" **after** the debounce, which causes your `searching` boolean to pass from true to false immediately. Try taping it **before** debouncing it and also to stop the loading animation **after** the actual call to API:

```
this.results$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
  tap(() => this.searching = true), // <= BEFORE DEBOUNCE
  debounceTime(300),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap((term: string) => {
    return (term && term.length > 0) ? this.myService.someCallToApi(term) : new Observable<Contact[]>();
  }),
  tap(() => this.searching = false) // <- AFTER THE API CALL
);
```

This is required according to SO's question about "search **while** you type" (understood as **from the very beginning of typing**).

Answer (score 0):

use the material spinner
https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview 
u will get docs here

Comment: It would be more helpful to pull out the relevant information rather than just posting links.

Comment: I see it's your first contribution so I'm not gonna downvote you, but it's not what I've asked for.